# execute npm script(s) of a project from a different project/ repo

Tags: node.js

I need to execute one of the npm scripts from a different node project.

What I tried:

```
const installingf = spawn('cd', ['[path to directory]', '&&', 'npm', 'run', 'test']);

installingf.on('message', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

installingf.on('error', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

installingf.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

but it does not work. It shows *child process exited with code 0* .

I tried `mkdir` to test if it gets executed but there are no directories created, it exits with code 0 but script is not executed.

Please help me figure out how to do this and if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: please explain the downvote. If  I am missing something in question I will add in the question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is because you're trying to execute one command, but you don't run the **cmd**.

The `cd` command doesn't exist on windows as long as you didn't create an alias. So you would need to run 'cmd' with arguments to run.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c','calc.exe']);

bat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});

bat.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});

bat.on('closed', (code) => {
 alert(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

- [IMPORTANT to read](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/2318).